# Error in awk code in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I'm using the ls command to list files to be used as input.  For each file found, I need to

1. Perform a system command (importdb) and write to a log file.
2. Write to an error log file if the first character of column 2, line 6 of the log file created in step 1 is not "0".
3. rename the file processed so it won't get re-processed on the next run.

My script:

```
#!/bin/sh
ls APCVENMAST_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9] |
while read LINE 
 do
       importdb -a test901 APCVENMAST ${LINE} > importdb${LINE}.log
 awk "{if (NR==6 && substr($2,1,1) != "0")      
       print "ERROR processing ", ${LINE} > importdb${LINE}err.log
        }" < importdb${LINE}.log
       mv  ${LINE} ${LINE}.PROCESSED
 done
```

This is very preliminary code, and I'm new to this, but I can't get passed parsing errors as the one below.

The error context is:

```
{if (NR==6 && >>>  substr(, <<< awk The statement cannot be correctly parsed.
```

Comment: What is this script intended to actually accomplish? There's almost certainly a better way that doesn't use awk (or ls) at all.

Answer (score 6):

Issues:

- Never double quote an `awk` script.
- Always quote literal strings.
- Pass in shell variables correctly either by using `-v` if you need to access the value in the `BEGIN` block or after the scripts *i.e.* `awk -v awkvar="$shellvar" 'condition{code}' file` or by `awk condition{code}' awkvar="$shellvar"`
- Always quote shell variables.
- Conditional should be outside block.
- There is ambiguity with redirection and concatenation precedence so use parenthesis.

So the corrected *(syntactical)* script:

```
 awk 'NR==6 && substr($2,1,1) != 0 {       
           print "ERROR processing ", line > ("importdb" line "err.log")
      }' line="${LINE}" "importdb${LINE}.log"
```

You have many more issues but as I don't know what you are trying to achieve it's difficult to suggest the correct approach...

- You shouldn't parse the output of `ls`
- Awk reads files you don't need to loop using shell constructs

Comment: Are you sure it  works? in my linux, awk can not take shell variable `line` directly, you have to use "$line".

Comment: I don't define a shell variable `line`. I define an `awk` variable line that has the same value as the shell variable `$LINE`. In `awk` if you do `$line` then you would be accessing the field number contain in `line` if any. `$` and `$` have completely different meaning in shell and `awk`. Awk is not part of the shell!

Comment: one point I don't understand. `Conditional should be outside block` why? awk has `if - else` statement, right? what if a script needs `{if(foo){code}else if (foo2){code} else if (bar){code} else{code}}` ?

Comment: @Imagination that is the structure of `awk` programs. You apply blocks of code to lines that match conditionals. Yes, they are case where using traditional `if` statements are appropriate but this isn't one. You're example would be `foo{code;next}foo2{code;next}bar{code;next}{code}`.

Comment: @sudo_O thank you for the explanation. so you are saying this point is only for this question. btw, the `if-else` is not as same as your `foo{code;next}` because before/after the `if-else` there could be other codes, it is not always stopping processing the current record. But to this specific question, you are right. thanks again.

Comment: @Imagination no this generally the case when using `awk`. If you have a genuine case for using a particular construct then use it. There are infinite cases to use `if` but when using `awk` the infinite case not to is larger.